# Where did the name "English" come from?

Tags: etymology, names

How is the name for one's own language created?

Comment: Being from **England** myself, I'm a bit crestfallen to realise this question could even be asked. I know the days when half the world map was coloured red are long gone, but have we really fallen that far below the radar?

Comment: @Rob one theory I've read -- purely FWIW -- when the romans cruised over to the british isles, the romans found us "angel"-like (blond, fair etc.)  I'm sorry I have no reference for this.  All of  the explanations below, are also commonly put forward.  I think it's fair to say "it's an open question, often discussed."  It's a great question!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your dismay seems to be based on the idea that the word "English" logically must have been derived from the pre-existing word "England". But that need not be the case; one could just as logically suppose that "England" was called "England" because *that's where the English speakers lived*. Or that both words "England" and "English" were created at the same time from some common root, like, say "Angle".

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Not really. I knew the substance of @drm65's Answer anyway. I just thought it was odd. Most people wouldn't ask, for example, where did the the word **Chinese** come from, surely? They'd ask about the word **China**.

Comment: @Joe Blow. The story you are hinting at refers to Pope Gergory who, the legend says, when presented with fair hair English slaves said in Latin "[Non Angli, sed angeli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Gregory_I#Famous_quotes_and_anecdotes)". In other words "Angels, no Angles". Which means that the word "Angle" already existed.  In other words, your comment was probably too quick.

Comment: @EricLippert, I marvel at how much you manage to read into @FumbleFingers' mind.  A precious gift indeed.  Lest you apply it to me as well, let me tell you in advance that I have never (publicly at least) claimed that the colour *green* was named so after the lush vegetation of medieval Greenland.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Ah, but China illustrates the original poster's point. Yes, *English speakers* call the Chinese languages "Chinese" by formation from "China". But in Mandarin, the country is called Zhōngguó ("the middle kingdom") but the language is called -- well, it is called all kinds of things: hànyǔ, meaning "the language of the Han people", or "pǔtōnghuà" meaning "the common language", or a number of other things. The question as I understand it is about *how the names for languages arise*; they need not be associated with the name of the country in that language.

Comment: @Alain: Ah, but have you ever claimed that wolves are called wolves because they wolf their food?  Or that fish are called fish because of their questionable business practices? No? Well, there goes another beautiful theory spoiled by a vexing fact.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: ty for all that. You've inspired me to post a question that I know will be easily answered by someone who knows, but which would be extremely difficult for me to find via Google...

Comment: @Eric, Sorry but **Chinese is no exception at all**. You "forgot" to mention the word *zhōngwén* 中文, the main word for *Chinese language*, which happens to be - precisely - the language of *zhōngguó* (中国).  As for the variant *hànyǔ* (漢語) it started as the language of the Han Kingdom *hánguó* 韩国 during the Warring States Period (战国时代) and later during the Han dynasty (汉朝 - Hàn Cháo aka 两汉 E/W Hans). On a general note please consider that posts and comments to EL&U are perused by many languages enthusiasts and that too basic ones like the question in this thread are likely to be frowned upon.

Comment: @Alain: Fascinating!

Comment: This would be an excellent topic for a blog post.

Comment: @Alain: I've been thinking a bit more about whether this is, as you claim, a "basic" question or not. The question of the origin of the word "English" does seem trivial and easily researched. But the larger question -- does *every* natural language follow the pattern "the Frobbit people of Frobbitland speak Frobbitish"? -- seems to me to be non-trivial. Are there exceptions to that rule? If it is generally true, *why is it true*? Any characteristic common to *every natural language* seems like it ought to be interesting.

Comment: @Eric Sure but this is Q. for *linguistics.se* rather than for EL&U. On the face of it this is quite logical. As you have rightly pointed out the central concept is the people. Not so long ago peoples were mostly nomadic and this lifestyle was the reason for their language identity (less contact with other languages). And there was no Frobbitland at all. So that it's difficult to claim that Frobbit stems from Frobitland whereas there are plenty of suffixes like *-land, -reich, -guó, -stan to support the opposite. The *foreign* name of languages is often eponymous to their root people as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Supposedly, it is a corruption of `Anglish`, aka: the language of the Angles. They were a Germanic tribe that [invaded/colonized Britain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon) after the Romans legions left, in concert with the Saxons, Jutes, and Frisians.

Oddly (and perhaps confusingly), the name the Celtic-speaking residents used to refer to the invaders (and later Normans used for their English-speaking subjects) was "Saxons". Often formally "Anglo-Saxon" was used instead. Also, the modern language found to be closest to English is [Frisian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisian_languages). Sadly, the Jutes get no such lasting recognition, except from historians.

This map from Wikipedia shows the supposed original invasion area in Kent, with a proposed tribal makeup.
[image]

The speculation is that the language started out as a sort of pidgin between the various German tribal languages. This is the theory for why the the word gender rules that a lot of other Germanic languages require were dropped.

Comment: Welsh is a Celtic language, and the Welsh word for Englishman is *Saes*.

Comment: @Hugo, "and the Welsh word for Englishman is Saes." Which I'm sure you know is a cognate of the word "Saxon" (G. "Sachsen"). In Gaelic, similarly, *Englishman* is "Sasunnach".  Regarding the Jutes, a reason often put forward to explain their relative oblivion is that they were a less important entity (possibly a smaller tribe under Frankish rule, from the lower Rhine; not from Jutland).  This is more consistent with their settlement area in Kent and Hampshire.  The Saxons instead would be a tribal confederacy and the Angles a simple tribe.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/English):

> Origin: 
>   before 900; Middle English; Old English Englisc,  equivalent to Engle  (plural) the English  (compare Latin Anglī; see [Angle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Angle)) + -isc -ish

And for "Angle" (link above):

> noun:
>   a member of a West Germanic people that migrated from Sleswick to Britain in the 5th century a.d. and founded the kingdoms of East Anglia, Mercia, and Northumbria. As early as the 6th century their name was extended to all the Germanic inhabitants of Britain.
>
> **Origin**: 
>   < Old English Angle  plural (variant of Engle ) tribal name of disputed orig.; perhaps akin to angle 2  if meaning was fisher folk, coastal dwellers

Comment: That's pretty how all the languages got their names. More interesting question is how the tribal names come to exist, but that's outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @RobGt: usually only artificially constructed languages like Esperanto are deliberately named.  Otherwise "the language of the XXX tribe" tends to end up as <adjective-derived-from-XXX>, with all the usual corruptions and ["Your Finger You Fool"](http://wiki.lspace.org/wiki/Your_Finger_You_Fool) misunderstandings.

Answer (score 5):

Although @drm65 and @T.E.D. have given correct answers to the original question, I thought I would deal with the “not Angles but Angels” reference raised in the comments on the question by @Joe Blow.

The “not Angles but Angels” story has no bearing on the derivation of “English,” but it is a real story related by Bede in *The Ecclesiastical History of the English People*, book 2, chapter 1, near the end of the chapter. Bede relates a story concerning Pope Gregory the Great encountering some English slaves for sale in the marketplace at Rome (this was before he became Pope himself, though). When told that they were pagans, he said:

> ‘Heu, pro dolor!’ inquit, ‘quod tam lucidi uultus homines tenebrarum auctor possidet, tantaque gratia frontispicii mentem ab interna gratia uacuam gestat!’ Rursus ergo interrogauit, quod esset uocabulum gentis illius. Responsum est, quod Angli uocarentur. At ille: ‘Bene,’ inquit; ‘nam et angelicam habent faciem, et tales angelorum in caelis decet esse coheredes. ([Ecclesiastical History II.i](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bede/bede2.shtml))

Which translates as:

> “Alas! what pity,” said he, “that the author of darkness is possessed of men of such fair countenances; and that being remarkable for such graceful aspects, their minds should be void of inward grace.” He therefore again asked, what was the name of that nation? and was answered, that they were called Angles. “Right,” said he, “for they have an Angelic face, and it becomes such to be co-heirs with the Angels in heaven.” ([Source](http://www.fordham.edu/halsall/basis/bede-book2.html), translator uncertain but likely L.C. Jane’s 1903 edition)

The exact phrase “non angli sed angeli” does not appear in the original Latin as you can see; it is a later distillation of the basic sentiment into a more succinct construction.

The original is much more fun than this translation; it’s basically an opportunity for Gregory — or for Bede — to show off his Latinity by making some amusing puns. I’m not fully familiar with how the story has been received in the centuries since Bede wrote, but as Joe Blow’s reference demonstrates, it retains some limited currency even today.

Lastly, note that it is not certain that the incident occurred, or if it did, that this is an accurate report.  Fair and unbiased reporting of history was not a high priority for Bede, who was after all writing an *ecclesiastical* history connecting England more firmly to the rest of Christendom.

Comment: Many thanks for that interesting trip down a medieval lane!

Comment: Bede is also the only real historical reference to the existence of the Jutes, and the source of nearly all the historical information I provided in my answer. An obscure monk living past the edge of civilization in his own time, but a hugely important person to us today.