# Why "English" but not "Anglish"?

Tags: etymology, phonology, old-english, historical-change, origin-unknown

Etymology of English from [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=English&allowed_in_frame=0):

> Old English **Englisc** (contrasted to Denisc, Frencisce, etc.), from **Engle** (plural) "**the Angles**," the name of one of the Germanic groups that overran the island 5c., supposedly so-called because **Angul**, the land they inhabited on the Jutland coast, was shaped like a fish hook (see angle (n.))

---

"[Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English)" article from Wikipedia:

> Old English (**Ænglisc, Anglisc, Englisc**) or **Anglo-Saxon** is an early form of the English language that was spoken and written by the Anglo-Saxons and their descendants in parts of what are now England and southern and eastern Scotland between at least the mid-5th century and the mid-12th century.

---

Also, Anglish is used as a resulting language of [linguistic purism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_purism_in_English). (coined by the author and humorist Paul Jennings). It is mentioned as English minus many of the non-Germanic elements.

---

**Questions:**

- Why didn't the name of the language become **Anglish** and survive till
  today?
- Etymonline says that it comes from **"Englisc"** but there are three different
  spellings of Old English and the root is mentioned as **Angul**. So why from Englisc but not Anglisc?

---

**Note:** There is this question asked before:
[Where did the name "English" come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33180/where-did-the-name-english-come-from/33184#33184)

Accepted answer mentions that English is the corruption of Anglish. But there is not much detail about it. Is it ever called Anglish then? When and how is it corrupted?

Also, English is "Anglais" in French. I'm not sure if it is beyond this website  if I ask why it is "Anglais" in French and if connection to other Germanic languages is related to this topic. The topic can go deeper in regards to origin of tribe names also. I may have missed some points and this can be asked in linguistics stackexchange as well.

Comment: Both Spanish *inglés* and Italian *inglese* derive from Old French *angleis*, so we see the same vowel-shift there as well.

Comment: Very simplistic answer: _i-mutation_ (also called _i-umlaut_). The /i/ in the following syllable caused /a/ to be raised to /æ/ or /e/ to approach it. Same reason (though with some minor differences) the plural of _tooth_ and _foot_ is _teeth_ and _feet_, and why the _Danes_ and those from _France_ speak (OE) _Denisc_ and _Frencisc_ (French).

Comment: “It is in the records of the fifth century that the word ‘Anglo-Saxon’ first appears. Indeed it was King Æthelstan who, among other high titles such as Bretwalda and Caesar, first styled himself *Ongulsaxna cyning*, that is, ‘King of the Angel-Saxons’. **But he did not speak ‘Anglo-Saxon’, for there never was such a language.** The king’s language was then, as now, *Englisc*: English.” —JRR Tolkien

Comment: “If you ever heard that Chaucer was the ‘father of English poetry’, forget it. English poetry has no recorded father, even as a written art, and the beginning lies beyond our view, in the mists of northern antiuquity. **To speak of an Anglo-Saxon language is thus wrong and misleading.** You can speak of an ‘Anglo-Saxon period’ in history, before 1066. But it is not a very useful label. There was no such thing as a single uniform ‘Anglo-Saxon’ period.” —JRR Tolkien

Comment: As the esteemed professor’s citation above shows in bold (those are one quote, only broken into two because of length limitations), despite what Wikipedia would have one believe, there was and is no such thing as ‘Anglo-Saxon’ as a language. King Æthelstan (~893–939) spoke Englisc, not the mythical and misunderstood — and non-existent — ‘Anglo-Saxon’.

Comment: Why "English" but not "Anglish"? [Because Umlaut](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299).

Comment: My missing point was umlaut then. But when did it happen exactly? And did it happen two times? Both a-restoration and i-umlaut? Also tchrist brought up another point. A detailed answer with sources would be good.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you’ve time this week, some detailed, non-comment answer from you that covered i-mutation not only Æthelstan’s *Englisc* but which also managed to rope in OF *angleis* > ES *inglés*, IT *inglese* would be much appreciated, even though it is strictly speaking a bit beyond the scope of ELU.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's "English" rather than "Anglish" because the vowel was subject to palatal umlaut. Umlaut is a process that occurred in many Germanic languages, Old English among them, and that caused vowels to change when they were followed by an [i] or [j]. The word *English* is from an Old English adjective *Englisc* derived from an Old English noun *Engle* that developed from an earlier form with *i* in the following syllable ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Engle) gives the form as "Proto-West Germanic *angli").

Before a nasal consonant such as [n] or [ŋ], it was usual in Old English for a short a-sound to turn into [e] when affected by umlaut. (Meizi Piao. 2012. "[An Analysis of I-Umlaut in Old English](https://s-space.snu.ac.kr/bitstream/10371/81463/1/06_Meizi%20Piao.pdf)". *SNU Working
Papers in English Linguistics and Language,* page 84)

Other examples of nouns showing the same change of original short *a to to Old English [e] due to umlaut are *bench,* from Old English *[benċ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/benc#Old_English),* from Proto-Germanic *bankiz, and *stench*, from Old English *[stenċ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stenc)*, from Proto-Germanic *stankwiz.

In *England* and *English,* the Old English [e] sound was further changed to [ɪ] due to the influence of the following velar nasal [ŋ]. The same sound change occurred in *string,* from Old English *[streng](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/streng#Old_English),* from Proto-Germanic *strangiz.

#### The variant vowels in Old English

The variants *Ænglisc* and *Anglisc* do exist in Old English, but I think they were less common than *Englisc.* They do not seem to have contributed to the ultimate outcome in Modern English.

I'm not entirely sure why alternative spellings with *Æng-,* *Ang-* and *Ong-* existed for this adjective in Old English, but the Oxford English Dictionary entry for the noun "Engle" has some discussion of its Old English byforms *Angle* and *Ongle* (Old English "a" often varied in spelling with "o" when it occurred in a stressed syllable before a nasal consonant such as /n/), saying that they "show alteration either after the place name (and combining form: see below) or after classical Latin *Anglus* Angle".

The note on the combining form reads:

> *Angel,* the name of the continental home of the Angles, occurs as a place name in English contexts from Old English onwards (in Old English as *Angel, Ongel,* in Middle English as *Angle;* in modern use also commonly *Angeln* after the German form of the name). Frequently in Old English as a combining form, sometimes in the sense ‘of or relating to the Angles (either on the continent or in England)’, but more commonly in the sense ‘of or relating to the English people or England’ (compare senses 1 and 2), as *Angelcyning* king of the English, *Angelcynn* the English people, (rare) the Angles, *Angelfolc* the English people

It seems that this place name did not show umlaut, so the vowel in the ethnonym and adjective might have been occasionally modified by analogy with the place name.

#### The general history of Old English æ

If one of the Old English alternative forms *Ænglisc* or *Anglisc* had survived until the present day, it might well have developed into the form "Anglish". The reference in [Robusto's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/168860/77227) to ash (æ or ae) changing into E is a bit inaccurate.

- In general, the Old English short æ/ash vowel developed to modern English "a", as in *ash* itself (from Old English *æsċe*), or in *Alvin* from *Ælfwyn.* Other examples of short ash corresponding to modern English "a" (not "e") are *hat* from Old English *hæt(t)* and *back* from Old English *bæc.* I'm not sure whether I can find an example of this outcome of short æ before a nasal consonant, though, since it did not generally occur in that context.
- The Old English long æ/ash vowel (written ǣ in modern texts) was spelled the same way as the previous vowel in Old English, but pronounced differently, and developed to modern English *e* or *ea*. That's what happened to the vowel in *even(ing)* mentioned in user2310967less's answer. But this isn't relevant to the word *English* since this word didn't have a long vowel in Old English.
- The Latin digraph "ae" found in *aether* and *aesthetic* is commonly simplified to e, but it is not the same thing as Old English ash: the digraph "ae" in Latinate words represents an original diphthong in Latin or Greek and was used in spelling far after the English letter ash had ceased to exist. In the context of Latinate words, "æ" is not a letter of its own: it is just a ligature of the "a" and "e" letters.

Comment: I for one have always puzzled over what’s behind the singular nature of *England/English* alone retaining the *e* spelling before the velar nasal with its /i/ vowel, despite how everything else got respelled to *i* for that. The OED notes: “England and English (and their derivatives) are **the only instances in modern standard English** in which the spelling with *e* has been retained in words showing raising of Middle English ĕ to ĭ before /ŋɡ/ (see further E. J. Dobson Eng. Pronunc. 1500–1700 (ed. 2, 1968) II. §77, and compare e.g. wing n., string n., and the forms cited at those entries).”

Comment: This is the only correct answer. I'm surprised the others have gotten upvotes and rewards. I guess people are just fascinated by æ

Answer (score 14):

In the journey from Old English to what we write today, the ash (Æ) tended to metamorphose into a simple E and various "ae" forms got reduced to just "e": Ælfwyn became Elvin, Æthelræd became Ethelred, aether and aesthetic became ether and esthetic (except when @Cerb spells them), and so on. The distinction was simply planed off over the centuries. When there was no need for the superfluous Æ (because its sound was rendered with a single letter) it got dialed way down in frequency. The same thing happened, more or less, with the thorn (Þ, þ) and eth (Ð, ð) characters, because the *th* digraph supplanted them.

An even more obvious influence involved the printing press. In the early days of typography, fonts were imported from Germany and Italy, and those countries did not use the oddball English characters, so substitutes had to be found. "E" substituted quite nicely for the ash, and "Y" for the thorn (as we see on the signs in front of all those cutesy Ye Old Whatever shops).

**Elaboration**

Asked for citations, I lazily looked to the Web first, but real scholarship in this matter is difficult to Google. Here are some not-stringently-academic citations, together with a disclaimer.

> The thorn was particularly popular as a sign for 'th' in Medieval English, but with the advent of printing came a problem. There was no thorn sign in the printing fonts, as they were usually cast outside of England. So, since the sign for thorn slightly resembled the lower-case 'y', that's what was substituted.
>
> The thorn continued to be used, but printing caused its eventual demise from the English alphabet. As mentioned earlier, lingering proof of its existence hangs on in the outmoded 'Ye'.
> [Thorn — Missing Letter of the Alphabet](https://web.archive.org/web/20140801075633/http://news.bbc.co.uk:80/dna/place-lancashire/plain/A2922077) (reposted with correct glyphs [here](https://h2g2.com/edited_entry/A2922077)).

---

> Ultimately, the letter was abandoned when printing began to streamline the alphabet and eliminate unnecessary letters. Æ was separated into AE, and the language moved on. However, you can still find ash used stylistically in names like Encyclopædia Britannica and ÆON.
> [Mighty Markup](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111033952/http://mightymarkup.com/tag/vowels-and-consonants/).

---

Disclaimer: I feel it only fair to point out that the reference books I have at hand (printed versions, so no linky-link), suggest that the ash (or *æsc* in OE), was pretty much gone by 1250 due to the influence of Norman French. This was a couple hundred years before the invention of the printing press, so we cannot accept that as the proximal cause. Still, Gutenberg almost certainly put the nail in the coffin of that and the other oddball characters (including *wynn* and *yogh* — look those up for your amusement and edification sometime).

Comment: Ey, the OED has my back on *aesthetic*, you know.

Comment: Think of that reference as my way of pinging you. ^_^

Comment: This is actually quite fascinating. Could you cite your resources for further reading?

Comment: One of the best and most readable histories of the English Language is David Crystal's "The Stories of English"

Comment: This is wrong. It is umlaut only.

Answer (score 4):

Vowels in English are tricky.

As @Robusto noted, in many cases Æ became E, as in *æfen* > *even(ing)*, *ælf* > *elf*, but in other cases it also became A, such as *æsc* > *ash*, *æcer* > *acre*, or *æfter* > *after*. Then again, you also have it turn to O, as in *æf* > *of*, *ænlic* > *only* and other oddities such as *æl* > *awl*.

Actually, *æfter* is an interesting case, since it made it through to modern English with both E and A, both as *after* and also as *eftsoons*.

It’s possible that at one point these represented differing regional standards for respelling Æ with more common vowels, and that like every other spelling form in English it represents a mishmash of different groups trying to write the same language and not quite succeeding but also not quite failing. But as far as I know there’s no incontrovertible evidence to prove it.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Janus Bahs Jacquet. If you study the vowels in *Anglisc*, you have the vowel *a* with the widest mouth opening and immediately after *a* you have the vowel *i* with the narrowest mouth opening. In order to make articulation easier, the deep tongue position of the vowel *a* is raised to *æ* and then to *e*.

Comment: It's not the width of mouth-opening, but the height.

Answer (score -1):

The E in "English" used to make more of the ash sound, but then shifted in modern English. The "Anglish" spelling has been revived though to represent the roots of the English language better. https://anglish.org

Comment: A different link to the same project was provided in the question already. This seems to condense points in other answers to the point where it's hardly a useful or informative summary.

Comment: It's also incorrect. The original sound was an /e/, mutated from /a/.

Answer (score -3):

POST WILL BE REWRITTEN WITH SOURCES AT A LATER DATE

English was a Germanic language (Modern English is a Romance language as 60% of its vocabulary is of Latin origin while 10% is still Germanic. So English lost its Germanic roots just as French and Norman did.) therefore it uses the Germanic name: English, and this comes from the Germanic words Engle, Engel, Englisc, Englisk, and Engleis.

Anglish is of Latin origin, comes from Anglii, Angla, Anglo, Angle, and Angles; and thus is not the correct name for the original German tribe that was part of an alliance (English, Frisian, Jute, and Saxon) to invade Britannia in terms of the Germanic languages.

There is zero reference of Anglo-Saxon until the modern era. It's a fake people and a fake language that never existed until 200 years ago.

The root word for English is all sourced from proto-Germanic, Old English, Old Saxon, and Gothic dictionaries and written text from the era from the Romans and Germans. Anybody who refers to themselves as Anglo-whatever should not be included with the Germanic race since they embraced Roman culture.

Here's a wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxons and in the second paragraph it mentions the etymology of the word "Anglo-Saxon". This should have been Englisc and Saexa in England (Britain) or Englisk and Sahsa in Saxony (northern Germany).

> The Old English ethnonym "Angul-Seaxan" comes from the Latin Angli-Saxones and became the name of the peoples Bede calls Anglorum[9] and Gildas calls Saxones.[10] Anglo-Saxon is a term that was rarely used by Anglo-Saxons themselves; it is not an autonym. It is likely they identified as ængli, Seaxe or, more probably, a local or tribal name such as Mierce, Cantie, Gewisse, Westseaxe, or Norþanhymbre. Also, the use of Anglo-Saxon disguises the extent to which people identified as Anglo-Scandinavian after the Viking age, or as Anglo-Norman after the Norman conquest in 1066.[11]

Comment: You have made some interesting if uncommon points about history and labels. Unfortunately, you seem to avoided answering the OPs question. Why 'E' instead of 'A'? Can you add anything to your answer that would address the linguistic question?

Comment: The "E" Should be used for those that desire German purity within the English language and since this is the original writing for Eng- before the Romans discovered the tribe. The "A" variant should be left for those that choose to embrace Latin since Modern English (like French) has developed into a Romance language and it would be better to distinguish the two languages from each other accordingly to the language group that their associated with: Romance or Germanic. People shouldn't confuse others regarding the etymology of the words English and Anglish both have distinctly separate origins.

Comment: Answering a 'why' with a 'should' is another uncommon method of communication that I am not used to. Also 'distinctly separate' sounds a bit hyperbolic (as far as absolute statements can be hyperbolic). At _some_ point there was one word that was used by two communities and the sound changes in the two paths diverged (either from the beginning or the word was borrowed and mangled into the different phonology). Is that what you are trying to get across?

Comment: This is difficult because the character limit.
Yes there was one word. Engel is found in proto-Germanic and Old Germanic. The changes in spelling of the words did occur (Englisc [Old English], Englisk [Old Saxon], Engleis [Frankish and Old French]) but the phonological shift didn't occur till later and this is only found in the Romance versions and North Sea Germanic.

Comment: Anglii [Latin] dates back as early as 125AD (the earliest reference I've ever found from the Romans).
Saxones [Late Latin] dates around mid 500AD. Anglorum [Late Latin] date around 700AD.
So it's easy to find where the phonological shift started to happen during the early development of the Romance languages with Latin and German being in proximity of each others influence.

Comment: Regarding your other question for "why" or "should"... I believe I gave a fair assessment when I answered with "should" as I offered a solution that is logical and fair to both parties in terms of English or Anglish. Modern English should be rebranded as Anglish since it's a Romance language as compared to Middle English which preserved much of its Germanic roots.

Comment: Anglish (Modern English) will continue to be spoken and will gravitate further will its evolution into the Romance languages while English should be officially classified as an extinct language since it will require a significant effort to revive English and restore it to its German roots.

Comment: If you rewrote your answer entirely using the historical comments as source, that would be a great complement to the others. Your 'should' justification about rebranding is not appropriate for a Q&A site since it is opinion.

Comment: Alright. I'll do it later and reformat the post so it's more clear for people to understand.

Comment: +1 because your answer offers a different perspective, but to call English a romance language because its *vocabulary* is  60% Latin is overreaching it a bit, although the percentage, technically, is correct. I'm not sure about the 10% German though, unless you are referring to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_Latinates_of_Germanic_origin

Comment: Yes. That why I said it should be Anglish because it's vocabulary is primarily Romance now and the Germanic is a minority. What I said is correct and it's being fair to both parties: English for German purist and Anglish for Anglos and whatever else they wish to call themselves since I've seen many names over the years.

Comment: @Joe  language is not only about vocabulary, it's about grammar, syntax, word order, phrasal verbs, idioms, etc.. And if I'm not mistaken, the most common words uttered and written in English are not derived from Latin but from German, so to call English a Romance language is pushing it. But I still like your answer.

Comment: Thank you but if you take into the account of Germanic grammer, syntax, word order etc... English has lost most of it. English also lost the gender nouns and verbs; and most of it's genetive, dative, and accusative parts for most of its vocabulary and we're not suffixing the words with their coorosponding vowels after the dominant consonants where this can still be found in every other Germanic language (for example: Alten Englisch compared to Old English compared to Oldan English). Middle English was the last stage that was still mostly German and shows it's similarities to Middle Saxon.