# Scottish, English, why not *Walish?

Tags: etymology, vowels, old-english

As the title question asks, and particularly in light of the Old English word *wælisc* apparently used to refer to "Welsh", when, why, and how did the English adjective meaning "of or relating to Wales" become "Welsh"? In particular:

Which of the apparently l Old English forms made it into Middle English?

Where (ie, what's the first Middle English appearance)?

Did the vowel change already worst) appear by the first appearance in Middle English, or did that come later?

Is there a general rule converting Old English æ to Middle English e?

In other words, when I ask "when, how, and why", I'm looking for a many details as possible of the historical and phonological process involved.

Comment: Perhaps if it were called _Walland_ and not _Wales_.

Comment: @ianmacdonald in which case I'd expect to see "Englandish".

Comment: Would you? Your proposition was "Walish". When changing England to English or Scotland to Scottish, the "land" bit is converted to a form of "ish". Hence my suggestion that it would need to be "Walland" to end up as "Walish".

Comment: @ian good point, don't know what I was thinking. I retract.

Comment: You are looking for logic and consistency in English?  Good luck!

Comment: @IanMacDonald - Won't that make people from England *Engish*, losing the 'l' from land?

Comment: @Tim I appreciate your comment. The same is true of Scotland, where an extra _t_ is injected. This is why I wrote "_to a form of "ish"_". The intention is to highlight that there is a suffix that is replaced, not appended (as Englandish would do).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that Scottish has the contracted form “Scotch” (also “Scots”, where the use of /s/ is I think a Scottish feature).

I would guess that the consonant cluster in the middle of “English” inhibited the development of any monosyllabic contracted forms—“Englsh” is not exactly a validly formed syllable in English.

Alongside *Welsh* we have *French* and *Dutch* (although in *Dutch* the contraction happened before the word entered English).

### Vowel

As far as I know, there is not a general rule converting Old English short æ to Middle English e. The general rule that I have seen given in linguistic sources is that Old English short æ corresponds to Middle English a. But there are complications.

The "Welsh" word had various vowel qualities in Old English; the form "wælisc" is only a standardized representation of one form. "West Saxon" is the dialect that is most commonly used as the standardized representation of "Old English" (e.g. in dictionary references to OE words), but it isn't the only dialect that contributed to modern English.

The number and distribution of "a-like" vowels differed between different dialects of Old English; I don't know enough about this topic to summarize it, but the OED entry for the word *Welsh* gives the following information:

- it classifies the forms into three main groups: 

  α. those like "OE Wilis-" (with i, y or u after the w)

  β. those like "eOE Uuelesc (*Kentish*)" (with e after the w)

  γ. those like "OE–eME Wælisc" and "ME–15 Walshe" (among others) (with æ or a after the w)

  Also a minor "δ." group with the vowel "o".
- in its "form history" section, there is extensive discussion of the history, including the following paragraph:

  > Some of the β. forms represent the Kentish reflex of early Old English *æ* with regular breaking to *ea* and i-mutation to *e*, and this is probably continued in south-eastern Middle English forms. However, the majority of the β. forms represent the Anglian reflex of *æ* with retraction to *a* before l plus consonant (compare the corresponding noun, Anglian Walh ), i-mutation of *a* to *æ*, and subsequent late Old English raising of this vowel to *e* in the east midlands and the north (compare A. Campbell Old Eng. Gram. (1959) §193(a), R. Jordan *Handb. der mittelenglischen Grammatik* (ed. 2, 1934) §62). The γ. forms show the expected reflex of the Anglian retracted and mutated vowel in the west midlands (Middle English *a*), but appear to be unusually widely distributed in Middle English. Although they become obsolete by the end of the 16th cent., *Walsh* survives as a form of the surname.

I think it's worth making another post specifically for the question about correspondences between OE "æ" and Middle or Modern English "e"--it seems to be a big, complicated topic, and I think making it a post of its own might attract more expert attention! I'm sure that there are other comparable examples; I'll try to find them when I have some time later.

An earlier question that seems relevant is [Why "English" but not "Anglish"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166490/why-english-but-not-anglish), although unfortunately it doesn't seem to have gotten any answers from experts.

Comment: And the vowel quality change after *w*?

Comment: The correspondence between the front vowels from OE to ME is indeed very complex – so complex, in fact, that I think it’s too broad to fit into a question or answer here. As far as I know, it’s not even fully understood. In _Welsh_, however, the main takeaway is that the _i_ in the eOE forms regularly caused i-mutation of the preceding _a/ea_ to _æ_, which was later raised to _e_ by a semi-regular sound change that occurred in some areas. The resulting form, _*Welish_ eventually lost its second syllable, and _Welsh_ ended up being the form that became the standard.

Comment: "English" formed from the two-syllable noun "Angle", so there was already a contraction of the syllabic "l" to form the adjective.

Answer (score 20):

It actually used to be some form of "Walish" that has since been contracted:

> **Welsh** Old English *Wielisc*, *Wylisc* (West Saxon), *Welisc*, *Wælisc* (Anglian and Kentish);

but it actually meant "foreign" or, more properly, "not Anglo-Saxon"; the Welsh called their country something else, and do to this day. In the Welsh language it's not Wales but [Cymru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wales).

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Welsh#etymonline_v_7910).

Comment: I was intrigued by OED's *Old English Wealh , (Anglian) Walh foreigner, Briton, Welsh person, slave, is cognate with Old High German Walh , Walah speaker of a Romance language (Middle High German Walch , Walhe foreigner, speaker of a Romance language, specifically Frenchman or Italian, German †Wahle ), Middle Dutch Wale speaker of a Romance language, **specifically Walloon or Frenchman** (Dutch Waal Walloon, speaker of a Romance language, especially French; compare the Old Dutch byname Wal , Walo )...* Never knew the Welsh roots stretched that far east!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: **Walloon** is kind of an a-hah moment for me.

Comment: So was the Anglian form definitely the one that made it into Middle English? Was the vowel change set by the first appearance in Middle English, or did that come later? Is there a general rule converting Old English *æ* to later *e*? I'll edit those questions into my main one - that's really what I wanted to know.

Comment: @Matt: The OE "ash" (*æ*) was pronounced like the *a* in *hat* and the *sc* digraph was pronounced like the current *sh* digraph. As is true today, there was a lot of latitude in the pronunciation of vowel sounds, though, so any "wæ" sound could be rendered in a variety of ways.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: if you want to go further east, the [Vlachs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlachs) of south-eastern Europe (roughly speaking what became Romanians) have a similarly cognate name

Comment: And the Hungarian word for ‘Italian’ is something like *olasz*, also apparently cognate.